# I am stuck and can't figure out why my countdown doesn't work. ( JS)

Tags: javascript

I have been messing around with a lot of JS videos for fun and I wanted to edit an alarm clock that I found to add a CountDown timer to it. But as much as I try I can't do it. A small note I am a beginner to JS ( and in general at coding ) and I wanted to ask if you can take a look at the code and see something I can't see? (Hopefully).

this is the part that I added and I am trying to get to work.

```
    const mafer = minutes - m;
    const safter = seconds - s;
    h2.innerText = `${mafer}:${safter}`;
```

The hall script.js

```
const currentTime = document.querySelector("h1"), selectMenu = document.querySelectorAll("select"), setAlarmBtn = document.querySelector("button"), content = document.querySelector(".content");

let alarmTime, isAlarmSet = false,
ringtone = new Audio("./files/ringtone.mp3");

const h2 = document.getElementById("H2");

for (let i = 12; i > 0; i--) 
{
  i = i < 10 ? "0" + i : i;
  let option = `<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`;
  selectMenu[0].firstElementChild.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", option);
}
for (let i = 59; i >= 0; i--) 
{
  i = i < 10 ? "0" + i : i;
  let option = `<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`;
  const minutes = selectMenu[1].firstElementChild.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", option);
}
for (let i = 59; i >= 0; i--) 
{
  i = i < 10 ? "0" + i : i;
  let option = `<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`;
  const seconds = selectMenu[2].firstElementChild.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", option);
}
for (let i = 2; i > 0; i--) 
{
  let ampm = i == 1 ? "AM" : "PM";
  let option = `<option value="${ampm}">${ampm}</option>`;
  selectMenu[3].firstElementChild.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", option);
}

setInterval(() => {
  let date = new Date(),
  h = date.getHours(),
  m = date.getMinutes(),
  s = date.getSeconds(),
  ampm = "AM";

  if(h >= 12) {
    h = h -12;
    ampm = "PM";
  }
  // if hour value is 0, set this value to 12
  h = h == 0 ? h = 12 : h;
  // adding 0 before hr, min, sec if this value is less than 10
  h = h < 10 ? "0" + h : h;
  m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
  s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;

  currentTime.innerText = `${h}:${m}:${s} ${ampm}`;

  if(alarmTime == `${h}:${m}:${s} ${ampm}`) 
  {
    ringtone.play();
    ringtone.loop = true;
  }
    const mafer = minutes - m;
    const safter = seconds - s;
    h2.innerText = `${mafer}:${safter}`;
}, 1000);

function setAlarm() {
  if(isAlarmSet)
  {
    alarmTime = "";
    ringtone.pause();
    content.classList.remove("disable");
    setAlarmBtn.innerText = "Set Alarm";
    return isAlarmSet = false;
  }

  let time = `${selectMenu[0].value}:${selectMenu[1].value}:${selectMenu[2].value} ${selectMenu[3].value}`

  if(time.includes("Hour") || time.includes("Minutes") || time.includes("Seconds") || time.includes("AM/PM")) {
    return alert("Please, select a valid time to set Alarm!");
  }
  isAlarmSet = true;
  alarmTime = time;
  content.classList.add("disable");
  setAlarmBtn.innerText = "Clear Alarm";
}
setAlarmBtn.addEventListener("click", setAlarm);
```

Any suggestions are welcome and thank you all in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What does your code do, and how is that different from what you're expecting?

Comment: It will help if you could add an example say on codepen or on jsfiddle.

Comment: I am getting this error message `Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received` what my code is supposed to do. Well when you set a timer it is supposed to give you a countdown of the time remaining until the countdown rings. Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ToxicGR/69du038f/

Comment: A quick note: minutes and seconds should be declared outside of the loops and not set to the value of insertAdjacementHTML. So set them to **let minutes = 0;let seconds = 0;**